# Espacio entre app:headerLayout y app:menu en NavigationView

Tags: java, android

Tengo actualmente un menu lateral el cual se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro ver donde esta el margen que tengo como de 20dps entre el QR y el primer ITEM del Menu, cabe mencionar que el qr donde termina es donde termina el Header del navigationView, tengo como una distancia por defecto entre el  `app:headerLayout` y el `app:menu`

El codigo de mi app:headerLayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="365dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientloginfondomenulateral">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/foto_gallery"
            android:background="@drawable/iconmenulateralperson"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombrePerfil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Laura Porteda"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foto_gallery"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CorreoElectronicoLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="096 456 215"
        android:textSize="16sp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nombrePerfil"

        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numerotelefonicomenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="brunogerman@gmail.com"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CorreoElectronicoLabel" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"

       android:layout_below="@+id/numerotelefonicomenu"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="75dp"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

       </RelativeLayout>


       <ImageView
           android:contentDescription="@string/RQ"

           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="150dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/redondnomenulateral"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           />

       <ImageView
           android:contentDescription="@string/RQ"
           android:id="@+id/myImage"
           android:layout_width="120dp"
           android:layout_height="120dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           />
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Mi app:menu

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblProfileInformation"
                    android:icon="@drawable/icono_info_personal"
                    android:title="@string/strLblInformacionPersonal_MENULATERAL" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblUpdateSecurityQuestion"
                    android:icon="@drawable/actualizacion_pregunta"
                    android:title="@string/strLblPreguntasSecretasl_MENULATERAL" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblChangePassword"
                    android:icon="@drawable/cambiar_contrasena"
                    android:title="@string/strLblCambioContrasenia_MENULATERAL" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblQr"
                    android:icon="@drawable/icono_hamburguesa_qr"
                    android:title="@string/strLblQR_MENULATERAL" />


                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblTitleSaldoMovimientosMenu"
                    android:icon="@drawable/icono_cobros_pagos"
                    android:title="@string/strLblCobroYPago_MENULATERAL" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblSplit_MENULATERAL"
                    android:icon="@drawable/icono_split"
                    android:title="@string/strLblSplit_MENULATERAL" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblTitleCards"
                    android:icon="@drawable/icono_cobros_pagos"
                    android:title="@string/strLblTitleCards" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/strLblDesAsociar"
                    android:icon="@drawable/icono_cerrar_cecion"
                    android:title="@string/strLblCerrarSession_MENULATERAL" />




</menu>
```

NavigationView:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ANCHOMENU"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
```

My style:

```
<style name="DrawerIcon" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Como puedo reducir ese margen entre el Header y el appMenu de mi navigationView??

Answer (score 1):

El ImageView del QR no termina dentro del header porque tiene una height estático porque eso la capa de te ve a fuera,Te agrego unas sugerencia espero que te funcione:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientloginfondomenulateral">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/foto_gallery"
            android:background="@drawable/iconmenulateralperson"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombrePerfil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Laura Porteda"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foto_gallery"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numerotelefonicomenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="096 456 215"
    android:textSize="16sp"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nombrePerfil"

    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CorreoElectronicoLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="brunogerman@gmail.com"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numerotelefonicomenu" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/layer2"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/CorreoElectronicoLabel"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="75dp"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

       </RelativeLayout>


       <ImageView
           android:contentDescription="@string/RQ"

           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="150dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/redondnomenulateral"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           />

       <ImageView
           android:contentDescription="@string/RQ"
           android:id="@+id/myImage"
           android:layout_width="120dp"
           android:layout_height="120dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           />
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Cuales son las sugerencias para que se funcione?

Comment: lamentablemente tu solucion no arregla la distancia entre el  header y el ap:menu